# why body overflow not working?

Tags: html, css

Why *body* **overflow:hidden** not working when viewport height is grater then css height?

ViewPort height is >700px and

css height is 300px

**codepen** http://codepen.io/vinaymavi/pen/aNMVYX

```css
div{
  border: 1px dashed;
  height:55px;
}
body{
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <body> 
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </body>
</html
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Why do you say it is not working? I've tested your code and It seems to be working fine. What is your expectation about `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Do you want to hide the view of overflowed content?

Comment: yes, i want to hide overflowed content.

Comment: in your css add html to body selector: `html, body {...`

Comment: Thank you @Banzay It is working fine after adding this *html, body*{...
My this question is only for learning so  why we need to do this?

Comment: over there: http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html is a great explaining of css features and differences of `body` and `html` elements.

Comment: Thank you @Banzay. nice article.

Comment: @vinaymavi - Note that the phrogz article is 12 years old and seriously out of date. It was probably a good description of how IE worked at the time it was written, but in particular, its description of how the `<html>` element's height works is completely wrong for modern browsers.

Answer (score 31):

From the [CSS 2.2 spec for the overflow property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the
>   viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an
>   XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the
>   'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport,
>   if the value on the root element is 'visible'.

That is, `overflow:hidden` set on the body element, is moved to apply to the viewport instead. To avoid that happening, you can set the `<html>` element to not be overflow:visible.

i.e. add `html { overflow:auto; }` to the CSS.

Comment: Thank you @Alochi.

Comment: Short answer: use `html { overflow:auto; } body {overflow: auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

Consider use a wrap around all divs. Like this:

```
<main class="main">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   ...
</main>

.main{
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: auto;` if you want the overflow to be visible with a scroll or `overflow: hidden;` if you want to hide it.
Also, Use parent div instead of using the body as the container..

See this:

```css
div{
  border: 1px dashed;
  height:55px;
}
#container{
  padding:10px;
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <body> 
    <div id="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @vinaymavi because this is not the purpose of the `<body>` this is accomplished by block elements such as `<div>` and `<section>` etc..

Comment: @vinaymavi No problem! Feel free to vote up if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define css for html as well as for body:

```
div{
  border: 1px dashed;
  height:55px;
}
html, body{
  padding:10px;
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed;
  height: 55px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you divs inside a wrapper

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed;
  height: 55px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```