# Body overflow: scroll not working as expected

Tags: html, css

In the following snippet I want the body element to have scrollbars, but it doesn't behave as expected. I set the html element to height:100% which gets the height of the Initial Containing Block, and the body is 100% gets the height of the html element. Now I set the overflow: scroll on body to get scrollbars because I don't want the boxes to be visible outside of the body, but they remain in the same place. What am I missing? This is just a test, I am learning and reading the CSS specs to understand how height on html and body works. Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  height:100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

html {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the first answer from these question -> [why body overflow not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506456/why-body-overflow-not-working)

You need to add `overflow: auto` to your html element.

Heres a pen: https://codepen.io/sebaLinares/pen/NOOdJM