# Why overflow: hidden works with div but not body

Tags: html, css, overflow, venn-diagram

I was playing [target #15 of CSS Battle](https://cssbattle.dev/play/15). Here's the code I used:

```html
<style>
  html {
    background: #09042a;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  html::before, html::after,
  body, body::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  html::before, html::after {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  html::before {
    left: 75px;
    background: #7b3f61;
  }
  html::after {
    left: 175px;
    background: #e78481;    
  }
  body {
    position: relative;
    left: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  body::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    background: #09042a;
    z-index: 15;
  }
</style>
```

That didn't give me a correct answer. However, if I add a `div` and use it instead of `body` (and use `body` instead of `html`), everything works as expected:

```html
<div></div>
<style>
  body {
    background: #09042a;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  body::before, body::after,
  div, div::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  body::before, body::after {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  body::before {
    left: 75px;
    background: #7b3f61;
  }
  body::after {
    left: 175px;
    background: #e78481;    
  }
  div {
    position: relative;
    left: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  div::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    background: #09042a;
    z-index: 15;
  }
</style>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Hope this will helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506456/why-body-overflow-not-working

Comment: Thanks. Precisely what I was looking for.